# Pop up advertisment on drupal site

Tags: drupal, web, web-hosting

I created a website with drupal 7.x and I registered to 000webhost site.

When I used cpanel service from 000webhost I hadn't got any advertisment on my site.

When I used filezila I observed that an advertisment reside to my site.

How can I remove it?

The site is (xprogrammers.webatu.com)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Changing to a played web hosting service could do the trick

Comment: Well, web servers cost money. Normally you pay for that with money or by showing someone's ads. Sounds like you ask for away to get around that. You will not find that here

Comment: Why are you so nervous? I don't know about it that's why I asked. I created a site to myself and I wonder why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I remembered recently using 000webhost.com for someone to make a simple HTML document with no advertisements and when I tested it, an advertisement popped up. You have to remember, providers of free services need to make their money somehow and I think that company decided to do so through many advertisements.

Your best bet is to try a new web hosting service and try a super simple HTML page to see if it displays as intended in all your testing environments.

Comment: This is from their official site:
000webhost.com ($0.00 webhost), is an industry leader in providing top class free web hosting services without advertising! There are no hidden costs, no adverts, and no restrictive terms

Comment: I have used them a couple of times. the first time I used them (about 8 years ago), it was advertisement-free. The last time I used them was maybe a year ago, and now they have advertisements. Maybe they did not get a chance to update their pages. Have you contacted them directly?

Comment: Ok I undersand. I wanted just to know how to install drupal on a site and I succeeded it. So now I can buy web space.  Thank you !!

Answer (score -1):

In the 000webhost cpanel service we choose remove inactivity ads.

And that's all